# How to get youtube stream url in form of docs.google.com

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-drive-api

There are some sites on internet where they use VideoJs player to play videos from youtube. when you look at their source code it is shows something like this.

https://r1---sn-npo7enel.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?expire=1412784736&ipbits=0&upn=nGmhLDiNQ9k&signature=9B6BA94D1BEF02870C22D4E941C48DC4E783C32A.BC6F3F47F563FC8E4FC98C374A7B5DD662E58304&itag=5&sver=3&id=o-AK3QyGdV8rMOYUPM8hXx6ac8f3WXvn8DZRbkvPtPruBi&mv=m&initcwndbps=16152500&source=youtube&sparams=id%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cmm%2Cms%2Cmv%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&ms=au&key=yt5&ip=128.199.133.159&mm=31&fexp=907257%2C916941%2C924630%2C924637%2C927622%2C930666%2C931983%2C932404%2C934030%2C944312%2C946013%2C946509%2C947209%2C948703%2C952302%2C953801&mt=1412763072

Im sure its not a google drive video. its youtube video but they are playing it from docs.google.com instead of googlevideos.com. How are they getting this link?

can anybody help me with that. I need this for some reason.

Comment: And the question is...? [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: the question is HOW TO GET YOUTUBE STREAM URL IN FORM OF Docs.google.com instead of googlevideos.com? Was i not clear enough?

Comment: No need to write in caps. The question's *body* wasn't clear to me.

Comment: Sites that do that have sniffed the traffic to discover the actual stream URL; however, this is against YouTube's terms of service and so you won't be able to do it with the YouTube API.

Comment: i can do this but even youtube itself stream video from c.youtube.com/videoplayback not c.docs.google.com/videoplayback. can you help m with that?

Comment: Suleman can u tell me how you get the stream url of youtube video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easy. Just replace the googlevideo.com in the youtube download url to c.docs.google.com

Thank you for asking this question. I know this after searching sometime.

YOUTUBE DOWNLOAD URL:
http://r2---sn-h557snee.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?sver=3&expire=1413317317&mv=m&mt=1413295596&ms=au&id=o-AFQYWPcu_Mgj7ApyBmoMopG3mkbxQgKxFOa3It4kBoSm&mm=31&source=youtube&initcwndbps=1216250&mime=video/mp4&ip=27.251.66.2&fexp=3300013,3300112,3300134,3300137,3300164,3310366,3310708,3312224,907257,916941,927622,930666,931983,932404,934030,936118,936222,946013,947209,952302,953801,953903&itag=18&sparams=id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,mime,mm,ms,mv,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&signature=49C37B73B3253F473F15AF6F8292D1628B63194C.7B10B7E983B7F4288933EBB0E821C84169653F0C&ratebypass=yes&ipbits=0&key=yt5&upn=KW7cc7l_RHs&title=Aaranya%20Kaandam

CONVERTED URL
http://r2---sn-h557snee.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?sver=3&expire=1413317317&mv=m&mt=1413295596&ms=au&id=o-AFQYWPcu_Mgj7ApyBmoMopG3mkbxQgKxFOa3It4kBoSm&mm=31&source=youtube&initcwndbps=1216250&mime=video/mp4&ip=27.251.66.2&fexp=3300013,3300112,3300134,3300137,3300164,3310366,3310708,3312224,907257,916941,927622,930666,931983,932404,934030,936118,936222,946013,947209,952302,953801,953903&itag=18&sparams=id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,mime,mm,ms,mv,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&signature=49C37B73B3253F473F15AF6F8292D1628B63194C.7B10B7E983B7F4288933EBB0E821C84169653F0C&ratebypass=yes&ipbits=0&key=yt5&upn=KW7cc7l_RHs&title=Aaranya%20Kaandam

Comment: How to get vevo video download links in this form , i am unable to get signature of vevo videos ?

Comment: @Srinivas08 vevo and all songs with heavy rights are disabled and cannot be streamed outside youtube